# Mule truststore and keystore

Tags: java, mule, mule-studio

if I create a trust-store and keystore for https inbound endpoints, my other https outbound endpoints start throwing exceptions.
An example is, if I create a HTTPS inbound enpoint connector like below,

```
<https:connector name="MuleHTTPS" cookieSpec="netscape"
        validateConnections="true" sendBufferSize="0" receiveBufferSize="0"
        receiveBacklog="0" clientSoTimeout="${APP.TIMEOUT}" serverSoTimeout="${APP.TIMEOUT}"
        socketSoLinger="0" doc:name="MuleHTTPS">
        <https:tls-key-store path="${HONDA.HTTPS.KEYSTORE}"
            keyPassword="${HTTPS.KEYSTORE.PASSWORD}" storePassword="${HTTPS.KEYSTORE.PASSWORD}" />
        <https:tls-server path="${HONDA.HTTPS.KEYSTORE}" explicitOnly="true" storePassword="${HTTPS.KEYSTORE.PASSWORD}"/>
    </https:connector>
```

The sqs inbound starts throwing peer not authenticated error. The config is

```
<sqs:config name="ReceiverAmazonSQS" accessKey="${AMAZON.ACCESS.KEY}"
        secretKey="${AMAZON.SECRET.KEY}" queueName="${AMAZON.QUEUE.NAME}"
        doc:name="SenderAmazonSQS" queueUrl="${AMAZON.QUEUE.URL}">
    </sqs:config>

<sqs:receive-messages config-ref="ReceiverAmazonSQS"
            doc:name="Receive Messages"/>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: add cacerts to the application.

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one HTTPS connector defined in a mule application, by default all the https endpoints, which do not have any connector defined, use the same connector. (Unless you define one more HTTPS connector and specify it in endpoint). This is the case with any transport in mule.